# How to change unicode character from Contextual forms "isolated" to General Unicode arabic in php

Tags: php, unicode, encode, arabic

i'm trying to convert a character like "ج"  in isolated form with encode => "\u062c" to "ج" General
Unicode with encode => "\ufe9d" .

anybody knows how can i convert this with PHP ?

Comment: all of them are UTF-8

Comment: I think it is in "compatibility", so a Unicode compatibility decomposition should be enough.